# Google Cloud ML Engine: Hyperparameter Tuning Cost as Function of MaxParallelTrials

Tags: google-cloud-ml

Quick question about hyperparameter tuning on ML Engine.  Assuming I'm setting `maxParallelTrials` to a value less than the number of cores on the ML Engine instance I'm using, is there any difference in cost between:

`maxTrials: 20
maxParallelTrials: 1`

and

`maxTrials: 80
maxParallelTrials: 4`

Since they should take basically the same amount of time?  Or is the number of cores being used a factor in calculating ML Units Consumed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There shouldn’t be any differences if they take the same amount of time (perhaps there could be a little overhead).

The number of cores used is not a factor. ML Units are calculated based on the region and the scale tier you choose.

[Training pricing](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/pricing#examples_calculate_training_cost_using_training_units) is calculated according to this formula:

```
(training units * base price / 60) * job duration in minutes
```

Where `training units` depends on the scale tier and region you select and `base price` depends on the region. For example, training in US with a PREMIUM_1 scale tier, training units would be 49.323 and base price 0.49 USD. You can find the complete pricing table [here](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/pricing#pricing_overview).